# Why is the result \StrCount not be used directly

Tags: xstring

I want to store a number which is obtained from \StrCount(package xstring) into a counter, as shown below, but it do not work, and fault message is given. Anyone can tell me the reason? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xstring,ifthen}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    some text
\newcounter{columnnumber}
\newcommand{\getcolumnnumber}[1]{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{:}
        {\setcounter{columnnumber}{\StrCount{#1}{:}}}
        %{\setcounter{columnnumber}{\StrCount{#1}{:} + 1}}
        {\setcounter{columnnumber}{1}}
}%

\getcolumnnumber{1:2:3:4}
\thecolumnnumber

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\StrCount` performs its computations with assignments to its internal registers and macros, which is unavoidable. As such, it cannot be directly used in the second argument to `\setcounter` which instead wants something that directly expands to an integer. The indirect path suggested in the answer is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to save the output of `\StrCount` to a macro (here `\tmp`). Also, it looks like you want to add 1 to the counter, so the column number is number of colons + 1, for that you can use `\stepcounter`.

As for the why, it has to do with expansion, that `\StrCount` isn't expanded when used in that context. (Or something like that.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xstring,ifthen}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    some text
\newcounter{columnnumber}
\newcommand{\getcolumnnumber}[1]{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{:}
        {\StrCount{#1}{:}[\tmp]\setcounter{columnnumber}{\tmp}\stepcounter{columnnumber}}
        {\setcounter{columnnumber}{1}}
}%

\getcolumnnumber{1:2:3:4}
\thecolumnnumber
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, the introduced \temp solve the problem, thank you. Yet why \StrCount can not be used directly as the value of a counter? Is there a better way without introducing a temporary macro?

Comment: @lyl As I mention in the edited answer, I think `\StrCount` is expanded properly when used in that context. Don't have any more insight than that though, sorry.

Comment: Many thanks. I understand that this is a problem about counter, not about \StrCount.